# create-react-app not working after installing yarn

Tags: node.js, reactjs, yarnpkg

I wanted to switch to YARN package installer so I installed it globally. When I did that my create-react-app doesn't work any more.

Log:

[image]

Comment: yarn create react-app app-name  |
This command is used to create a new app using yarn command

Answer (score 0):

`npx` is used to run npm packages without installing them in your system. But if you already have a package like `create-react-app` installed globally on your machine with yarn or npm, then you can just write `create-react-app learning` instead of `npx create-react-app learning`